# question on vector calculus notation

Tags: notation, vector-analysis

I just have a question about the vector calculus notation:
$$(u \cdot \nabla)u$$ Is that the same as $( \nabla \cdot u)u$?

Comment: @Jake $u\cdot \nabla$ is commonly used to indicate the operator $$u_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+...+u_n\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n},$$ which is the directional derivative operator in the $u$ direction.

Comment: $$\hat x_i\cdot((\nabla \cdot \vec u)\vec u)=u_i\partial_ju_j\,$$

$$\hat x_i\cdot ((\vec u\cdot \nabla)\vec u)=u_j(\partial_ju_i)=\partial_j(u_iu_j)-u_i\partial_ju_j$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these are not the same. The vector $(u\cdot\nabla)u$ is the directional derivative of $u$ in the direction of $u$. It may not be (and probably isn't) parallel to $u$ at each point. The vector $(\nabla \cdot u)u$ is $u$ multiplied by its divergence. It is always parallel to $u$ at each point.

Comment: so if $u$ is two dimensional, then $(u \cdot \nabla)u=u_1 u_{x_1}+u_2 u_{x_2}$, which is also two dimensional?

Comment: No, $$(u\cdot \nabla)u=\binom{u_1(u_1)_{x_1}+u_2(u_1)_{x_2}}{u_1(u_2)_{x_1}+u_2(u_2)_{x_2}}.$$

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much!